# Bug with the Time Wound in Alduin's Bane on the Switch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is a major, game-breaking problem. In the Alduin's Bane quest, I go to the Time Wound with the Elder Scroll and enter the vision but nothing happens. Everyone just stands around and the dragon doesn't show up, which is to say I was transported back in time (hence entered the vision) and the characters speak their lines but Alduin never appears. The game effectively ends. What is the fix for this? It has supposedly been patched on Steam so why is it showing up on the Nintendo Switch? The **only fixes** I have found *require the **console***, which is not available on the Switch.

**References**:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/613935404190484207/
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/f/p/2647836273410049493

**Does anyone know how to fix this?**

Comment: So you also already tried doing other quests first?

Comment: According to https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alduin%27s_Bane "The cutscene in the Merethic era may not trigger or complete, leaving you stuck there. — Doing other quests and then returning may fix this."

Comment: I'm going to try it and post the results here but it strikes me more as ignoring it and hoping it'll go away than as any kind of an actual fix. Maybe a workaround...will follow up with an update.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you mean by "Everyone just stands around and the dragon doesn't show up"?  Were you blinded by the Elder Scroll and then transported back in time? Or did that not happen? Also, according to the OP of https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/vmgex3/i_cant_read_the_elder_scroll_at_the_time_wound/ - "fast traveling away and then back" fixed the issue for them.

Comment: The problem has been remedied. I uninstalled Skyrim, reinstalled Skyrim, performed an update, rebooted. When I launched Skyrim there was a "survival mode" prompt. Then when I attempted to use the elder scroll to learn "dragonrend" the scripted scene played out correctly.